# how to solve - "too many text index for .." - mongodb error?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, indexing, full-text-search

Getting this error and don't know why, here is the snippet of the function that deals with **mongodb** full-text search:

```
...
db.collection.ensureIndex({ description: 'text' }, { name: 'TextIndex' });

db.collection.runCommand('text', { search: 'my query' }, function (err, res) {
   console.log(res); 
  // { 
  //   "message": "failed to search items for user by query", 
  //   "error": "too many text index for: .. 
  // }
});
```

The same problem appears in mongo shell as well..

Comment: Are you sure you only have one index: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8127 ?

Comment: @Sammaye yes, the same error is when I simply try to run this command via mongo shell

Comment: For those who's interested about indexes - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/ 
as for solution: it was to drop previous created indexes directly from the shell - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/