# MongoDB full text search index: error: too many text index for, why?

Tags: java, mongodb, full-text-search, mongodb-java

I have one problem, I have collection and I want to set text search index to 2 fields(description and title). But when I add second index I get following error and text search stopped working.

```
{ "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "too many text index for: testdb.users"}
```

when I delete one index search start work again. what is the problem? One collections support full text search index only for one field????

I am using the current version of mongodb under windows and I am using mongodb java driver API.

Thanks

Comment: You have more than one text index, currently you can only have one, what you want is this link: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/

Comment: Problem is, then I add second text index to the same collection, full text search stop work and I get that error. Seems for multiple fields text search not working.

Comment: Can you show us an example of where the multiple fields is not working? You should be able to ensure one index across multiple fields

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385853/how-to-solve-too-many-text-index-for-mongodb-error (in the comments)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MongoDB only allows one text-index per collection.

But you can use a text-index which spans multiple fields:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( {
    description: "text",
    title: "text"
} );
```

That way you will get results when the phrase you are searching for is found in either. When this is not what you want, like when you have two search-queries which each return results from one of the fields but not the other, you have two options.

1. use a multi-field text index, but discard the results which come from the wrong field on the application layer.
2. extract one of the two fields to a different collection. The documents in that collection could either contain full copies, redacted copies or just the field you index and the `_id` of the original document.

Comment: Thanks it works! De facto one index for multiple fields is true, I tried to add one index for one field whats why mongo fails. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I'm semi-new to node and I don't know where to put this syntax.  Where is 'db' coming from?

Comment: @ac360 The syntax used in this question and answer applies to the mongodb command-line shell.

Comment: Do you know *why* they have this limit?  I tried searching around, but I haven't found a reason, just statements that the limit exists.

Comment: This seems like a pretty big limitation.  It needs to get fixed because I may have to rethink my choice of DBs in the future.

Answer (score 2):

To create a text based index on a key, use command `db.collectionName.ensureIndex({'textColumnName': 'text'})`. After this index is applied, use the search commands to search for a word i.e. `db.collectionName.find({$text: {$search:'your text here'}})`. There is a text score based on which the results are ranked, to see it project it in the score key like this : `db.collectionName.find({$text: {$search:'your text here'}}, {score: {$meta: 'textScore'}}).sort({score: {$meta: 'textScore'}})`.

If we create a text index on the `title` field of the `movies` collection, and then perform the text search `db.movies.find( { $text : { $search : "Big Lebowski" } } )`. The following documents will be returned, assuming they are in the movies collection:

- `{ "title" : "The Big Lebowski" , star: "Jeff Bridges" }`
- `{ "title" : "Big" , star : "Tom Hanks" }`
- `{ "title" : "Big Fish" , star: "Ewan McGregor" }`

This is because, there will be a ***logical OR***ing on `Big` & `Lebowski`.